# Unifying different 2d array layouts in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on an application that gets a list of x and y coordinates from various data sources.
Depending on which data sources I need to go to (which is outside my control), there are multiple ways the data is returned.

- an array of x and y values - [[x1,x2,x3...],[y1, y2, y3...]]
- an array of x,y pairs - [[x1,y1],[x2,y2], ...]
- a dictionary of x:y values - {x1:x2, x2:y2, x3:y3, ...}
- a numpy array of x and y values - array([[x1,x2,x3...],[y1, y2, y3...]])
- a numpy of x,y pairs - array([[x1,y1],[x2,y2], ...])

Using isinstance and len/shape I know I can solve this problem with a switch statement.  I was wondering if there was a better way to convert these to a consistent format, or to read these in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to `achampion's` conversions:

You can construct a dictionary from a list of pairs:

```
dict([[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]) == {x1:x2, x2:y2, x3:y3, ...}
```

`np.asarray` can convert lists to arrays, and happily passes an array through unchanged.  `numpy` functions often pass their inputs through `asarray` (or a variant) to insure that the inputs are arrays of known dimension.

And array transpose is the equivalent of that list `zip(*...)`.

```
np.asarray([[[x1,x2,x3...],[y1,y2,y3...]]) == np.asarray([(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)...]).T
```

I don't think you can go from dictionary to array without an intermediary list.  But a `(n,2)` array works just as well as a list of pairs as input to `dict()`.

So it is easy to convert one layout to another, but I don't think there is one function that does it for all of your layouts.

Is any one of these layouts more convenient for further processing?

Pseudo code might be:

```
if x is a dictioary:
   x = convert_to_list(x)
x = asarray(x)
if x.shape[0]==2 and x.shape[1]>2:
    x = x.T
# [[1,2],[3,4]] is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to treat these structures identically (they aren't all ducks).
However, it's fairly easy to convert into a consistent format, make your pick and convert into that format, e.g.

```
zip(*[[x1,x2,x3...],[y1,y2,y3...]]) == [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)...]
zip(*[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]...]) == [(x1,x2,x3...),(y1,y2,y3...)]
list({x1:x2, x2:y2, x3:y3, ...}.items()) == [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)...]
dict([(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)...]) = {x1:x2, x2:y2, x3:y3, ...}
```

Numpy arrays can largely be treated the same as Python lists.